# Finding the minimum of $z+d$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Suppose that $z, d\in \mathbb{Z}$ are a $3$-digit positive integer with $24\text{gcd}(z, d) = \text{lcm}(z, d)$. How can we find the minimum of $z+d$?

$$\begin{align}\text{gcd}(z, d)\text{lcm}(z, d) = zd&\iff 24\text{gcd}^2(z, d) = zd \\\ &\iff \text{gcd}(z, d) = \sqrt{\frac{zd}{24}}\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}\text{gcd}(z, d)\text{lcm}(z, d) = zd&\iff \frac{\text{lcm}^2(z, d)}{24} = zd \\\ &\iff \text{lcm}(z, d) = \sqrt{24zd}\end{align}$$

If $\text{gcd}(z, d), \text{lcm}(z, d)\in \mathbb{Z}$ are both integers, then the numbers $\displaystyle \frac{zd}{24}, 24zd\in \mathbb{Z}$ both have to be a perfect square. However, I am not sure where this would lead us

Answer (score 1):

As the entire problem is symmetric with respect to $z,d$, we may assume, without loss of generality, that $z\leq d$.  Also, to ease up on space, I will define $g := \gcd(z,d)$.

In these terms, your equation $24\text{gcd}^2(z, d) = zd$ can be written
$$24 = \left(\frac{z}{g}\right)\left(\frac{d}{g}\right)$$
where we note that $\gcd(z/g, d/g) = \gcd(z,d)/g = 1$, so this is a factorization of $24$ into relatively prime positive integers.  There are only two ways for this to happen with $z \leq d$:
$$\begin{array}{cccc}(1) & \frac{z}{g} = 1, \frac{d}{g} = 24, & \text{ or equivalently } & z=g, d=24g \\ \\ (2) & \frac{z}{g}=3, \frac{d}{g} = 8, & \text{ or equivalently } & z= 3g, d=8g.\end{array}$$

We can dispose of the first case quickly by noting that if $z,d$ are three-digit numbers, then $g = z \geq 100$ and $2400 \leq 24g = d < 1000,$ which is a contradiction.  Therefore we're left with $z=3g$ and $d=8g$.

Once again applying the assumption that $z$ is a three-digit number: $3g = z \geq 100$ gives $g \geq 34$ so $$z+d = 3g + 8g = 11g \geq 374.$$

Now we need to check that our candidate $z,d$ are valid.  When $g=34$, we have $$z = 3(34) = 102, \\ d = 8(34) = 272$$
both of which are three-digit numbers, and
$$\gcd(z,d) = \gcd(102,272) = 34 \\ 24(\gcd(z,d))^2 = 24(34^2) = 27744 = (102)(272)=zd.$$

Since everything checks out, we can conclude the minimum of all such $z+d$ is $374$.

Answer (score 0):

You’re off to a great start! You have the equation in a form that’s much easier to work with:

$$ 24gcd(z,d)^2 = zd $$

Here’s an idea when you see a problem like this: play around with the numbers until you find *a solution* to it, and only then look at minimizing your other expression, $z + m$ in this case.

Try that and see if it gets you anywhere. Otherwise keep reading.

> It would be “nice” if the solution was such that $gcd(z,d)$ was 1. It simplifies the equation greatly. It becomes:

> $24(1^2)=24=zd$

> Now by inspection, 8 and 3 satisfy the conditions. Their product is 24 and their gcd is 1. The only other pair which satisfies that is 24 and 1, but clearly their sum is greater, so we can ignore it. Now the problem lies in proving that this minimizes $z+d=8+3=11$

> Notice that if some integers $a$ and $b$ satisfy the equation, then any *scalar multiples* of them also satisfy the equation. This is easy to show. This means that by *dividing* by those scalars, you can get a solution with a gcd of 1 whose sum is strictly lesser. Therefore, our guess earlier was correct! 8 and 3 is the only solution with a gcd of 1, therefore 11 is the minimum.

> Now to apply the other condition, that they are three digit numbers. We now know that all solutions are scalar multiples of (8,3), so we simply multiply this by the minimum scalar to bring it in the range, 34. So the solution which minimizes in that range is $z+d=34(8+3)=34(11)=374$

Comment: That doesn't actually fix it (we don't care _a priori_ which is smaller between $3+8$ and $1+24$).  Rather, it's just that there's no $k$ such that $1\cdot k, 24\cdot k$ are both three-digit numbers

Comment: That works too. There’s no flaw though, the sum is larger, any scalar multiple of the sum will also be larger.

Comment: It's true that for any $k$, we would have $(3+8)k < (1+24)k$, which I think is what you're saying, but this isn't the applicable inequality, as $k$ is a meaningless parameter here.   It's false that for any $k_1, k_2$, we'd have $(3+8)k_1 < (1+24)k_2$ (until you consider the applicable domains of $k_1, k_2$ respectively).

Comment: Consider for instance if we were considering the integral multiples of $(3,8)$ against the integral multiples of $(5,8)$.  Then certainly it's true that $3+8 < 5+8$, but this is a meaningless comparison.  The applicable comparison would instead be $(5+8)\times 20 < (3+8)\times 34$

Comment: That didn’t seem to me to be the “hard part” of this problem, so I didn’t devote very much attention to it. It was not meant to be a complete proof, but just to help the OP over their hurdles. Good lord.

Comment: You, I see, didn’t even post an answer, just comments, which give a convoluted and unintuitive semi-proof. “Let he who is without sin throw the first stone”

Comment: _Just call me the devil in the details_.  In all seriousness, my intent in leaving these comments is to have you fix it and then remove the comments (you may have noticed I've already done so with my first couple comments, as they were regarding a previous version)